# Navigation Tree: Subsections

Tags: beamer, formatting, presentations

**Problem**

Good evening everybody.

Calling the beamer-class.

Is it possible to have a navigation tree as shown in a sidebar in the header instead; i.e. showing all sections and subsections and uncovering only the current one?

**Example**

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{frame}
First frame without title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\begin{frame}
Second frame without title.
\end{frame}
\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{frame}
Third frame without title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\begin{frame}
Fourth frame without title.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @touhami: Thanks for the help with formatting. :)

Comment: Does `\useoutertheme{smoothtree}` give you waht you want?

Comment: @Freeze_S you're welecome (I will delete this comment)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Almost but then only the current section is displayed in the tree...

Comment: Then perhaps `\useoutertheme{split}`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Also not yet. I'd like to have the sections horizontally aligned and the all subsections below the corresponding sections while the current section and subsection being uncovered the others being transparent. Is this possible?

Comment: Both `(smooth)tree` and `split` use direct commands to insert titles. There is no easy to extend them to include the whole TOC.

Comment: @Symbol1: But they only show the current section and subsection. So there's no easy way to get that into the header? Sad. :(

Comment: Aha, so it is just an aligning question. I withdraw my comment. A quick idea: while `smoothtree` uses `\insertsectionhead` and `\insertsubsectionhead`, you can replace them by `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` and `\insertsubsectionnavigation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is not so easy.

Anyway, recall that there is an outer theme `miniframes`:

> This theme installs a headline in which a horizontal navigational bar
>   is shown. This bar contains one entry for each section of the
>   presentation. Below each section entry, small circles are shown that
>   represent the different frames in the section. The frames are arranged
>   subsection-wise, that is, there is a line of frames for each
>   subsection.

Each of these circles is drawn by `\slideentry`. This command reads the data of the upcoming circle:  Which page does it corresponds to? Which part/(sub)section does it belongs to? and so on. And then decides whether it corresponds to the current (sub)section, as well as whether it is indeed the current page. Finally draws/fills a circle with proper color.

[image]

So... what do we want now? We do not want circles but titles of subsections. So our `\slideentry` should read the same data first, decide the incidence relation then, and draw... NO... typeset the subsection title with proper color.

In the following approach, I redefine `\slideentry` based on its original definition. Only contents in `\hbox{\beamer@link(#4)...}` are modified.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \def\insertsubsectionhead{#5}%
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
          \usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
          \ifnum1=#3
            \ifnum\c@section=#1
              \ifnum\c@subsection=#2
                \usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}
              \fi%
            \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot hided} % In fact there is no such template. Hence nothing happens. Like there is something but hided
            \fi%
          \fi
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }


\begin{document}
    \section{Section1}
        \subsection{Subsection11}
            \frame{{Frame111}}
            \frame{{Frame112}}
            \frame{{Frame113}}
        \subsection{Subsection12}
            \frame{{Frame121}}
            \frame{{Frame122}}
            \frame{{Frame123}}
            \frame{{Frame124}}
        \subsection{Subsection13}
            \frame{{Frame131}}
            \frame{{Frame132}}
    \section{Section2}
            \subsection{Subsection21}
            \frame{{Frame211}}
            \frame{{Frame212}}
            \frame{{Frame213}}
        \subsection{Subsection22}
            \frame{{Frame221}}
            \frame{{Frame222}}
            \frame{{Frame223}}
            \frame{{Frame224}}
        \subsection{Subsection23}
            \frame{{Frame231}}
            \frame{{Frame232}}
        \subsection{Subsection24}
            \frame{{Frame241}}
            \frame{{Frame242}}
            \frame{{Frame243}}
    \section{Section3}
            \subsection{Subsection31}
            \frame{{Frame311}}
            \frame{{Frame312}}
            \frame{{Frame313}}
        \subsection{Subsection32}
            \frame{{Frame321}}
            \frame{{Frame322}}
            \frame{{Frame323}}
            \frame{{Frame324}}
\end{document}
```

If you replace `hided` by `shaded`, you can get

[image]

---

## Explanation

Beamer introduces **template** system to help users control the styling in an easy way. Almost everything you see on a page is associated to a template: title, header/footer, blocks (if any), and navigation symbols (usually at lower right corner).

In most cases, preexisting templates are quite sufficient. So people tend to apply a **theme**, which is nothing but collection of templates. In your case, your requirement is very closed to `miniframes` the theme. So I would like to apply `miniframes`, and then change something.

To understand how to modify `miniframes`, we have to understand how **navigation** system works. Briefly speaking, Beamer create a `.nav` file, much like a `.toc` file, that contains everything you would like to navigate to. This is how `.nav` looks like

> ```
> \beamer@endinputifotherversion {3.36pt}
> \headcommand {\sectionentry {1}{Section1}{1}{Section1}{0}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@sectionpages {1}{0}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@subsectionpages {1}{0}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@subsectionentry {0}{1}{1}{1}{Subsection11}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@subsectionpages {1}{0}}
> \headcommand {\slideentry {1}{1}{1}{1/1}{Subsection11}{0}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@framepages {1}{1}}
> \headcommand {\slideentry {1}{1}{2}{2/2}{Subsection11}{0}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@framepages {2}{2}}
> \headcommand {\slideentry {1}{1}{3}{3/3}{Subsection11}{0}}
> \headcommand {\beamer@framepages {3}{3}}
> ...
> ```

So... let's say we want to create a navigation bar contains only section titles. Then we should define `\sectionentry` to return the section title, and define other commands to do nothing.

How about `miniframes`? It basically defines `\sectionentry` to return the section title, and defines `\slideentry` to draw a circle. For us, we do not want it to draw circle. What we want `\slideentry` to do is check if this is the first frame of a subsection. If it is, return the subsection title. If not, do nothing. And that is how we get a "`minisubsections`" style

#### How about `\beamer@subsectionentry`? Is not it designed for returning subsection title?

Indeed it is. But If I started with `\beamer@subsectionentry`, I would have to deal with the alignment by myself.

Leave comments if you want to ask about any specific command.

Comment: Great!! :D Can you still make the subsections of the other sections be shown (covered)? Now it is only the subsections shown from the current section. Besides I'm curious can you explain a little what the particular commands mean. I got now that makeatletter assigns to '@' the category code 11 instead of 12.

Comment: @Freeze_S see my edit.

Comment: Ah ok so the beamer class creates besides a toc-file also a nav-file. In that it stores all information independant of the chosen theme resp. templates? And depending on the chosen theme resp. templates the information stored in the nav-file will be interpreted differently? By the way a theme is something like a bundle of templates so for example 'Singapore' chooses templates like 'section in head/foot'?

Comment: Which template do I have to specify with shaded/hided?

Comment: @Freeze_S Correct! (Well... sometimes a theme chooses a preexisting template, sometimes it **implements** a new one.) For your last question, search `hided` in my code. And you will see there are `\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}`, `\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}`, and `\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot hided}`.

Comment: Are the themes stored in sty-files?and the templates in the Beamer class file?

Comment: @Freeze_S Nope, because Beamer is so enormous that the author separated its contents into [SO MANY FILES](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base). There you can see a theme is something like `beam­erthe­meSin­ga­pore.sty`. And Singapore then includes another theme like `beam­er­outerthe­mem­i­niframes.sty`. On the other hand templates can be defined everywhere.

Comment: Aaaah thanks wasn't sure about what template to choose. Thank you soooo much!!!! :D

Comment: It really depends which type of templates are you concerning. For example if you are interested in templates related to TOC, there is a exclusive file `beamerbasetoc.sty`. Talking about colors? there are files for colors. As I just said, the *SYSTEM* is a monster...

Comment: I can imagine. ^^ That seems all very complicated!! Thank you sooo much, again!!! :D